# Copy data repeatedly based on cell content in above row

Tags: excel, vba

I am doing an Excel VBA Project.

I have data in an excel file, Rows 1 and 2 as follows

```
Ann <blank> Ben <blank> Sam <blank>

P      S
```

I want to copy `P` and `S` repeatedly in my Row 2 until the point where my cell above is `blank + 1` so that my table gets filled as such:

```
Ann <blank> Ben <blank> Sam <blank>

P      S     P     S     P     S
```

How do I write the VBA code for this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this (changing variables `firstRowNumber` and `secondRowNumber` to row numbers that are true for you):

```
Sub test()
   Dim lastColumn As Long
   Dim firstRowNumber As Integer, secondRowNumber As Integer
   Dim firstCollumnNumber As Integer
   Dim rng as Range
   'number of first row'
   firstRowNumber = 3
   'number of second row'
   secondRowNumber = 4
   'number of first column where you data starts'
   firstCollumnNumber = 1 
   'determining column number of last non empty cell in first row'
   lastcolumn1 = Cells(firstRowNumber, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

   'initial values in first and second column'
   Cells(secondRowNumber, firstCollumnNumber) = "P"
   Cells(secondRowNumber, firstCollumnNumber+1) = "S"

   'fill second row with values'
   Set rng = Cells(secondRowNumber, firstCollumnNumber)
   Range(rng, rng.Offset(0, 1)).AutoFill _
      Destination:=Range(rng, rng.Offset(0, lastcolumn1 - firstCollumnNumber + 1)), _
      Type:=xlFillDefault
End Sub
```